# Controlling the influence of variation in a factor

Tags: random-variable, biostatistics, ancova

I sampled communities in different habitats along a continental margin. Depth is a strong structuring factor in the ocean. To mitigate or control the influence of the depth factor and in a comparison of habitats, would it make more sense to perform a 2-way ANOVA with with depth as random or an ANCOVA and make depth a covariate?

Comment: You realy need to give us some more context here!